# How Can i add row to my table that is auto increment that will affect my primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i add this id that which is '2' on my table where i already ahve an id which is '2' i would like to ask about Identity

```
 INSERT INTO `f4`.`tbl_te` (
`id` ,
`name` ,
`quantity` ,
`price` ,
`subtotal`
)
VALUES (
'2', 'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55'
)
```

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Do you want to add a new row with the same key or `UPDATE` the current row?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a primary key, it needs to be unique - you need to change the ID you're trying to add. Alternatively, if it's an auto_increment, you don't need to specify it in your INSERT at all:

```
 INSERT INTO `f4`.`tbl_te` (
`name` ,
`quantity` ,
`price` ,
`subtotal`
)
VALUES (
'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55'
)
```

That will assign it the next available key.

If you just want to change the existing values:

```
UPDATE `f4`.`tbl_te` SET
    `name`='Mushroom Omelet',
    `quantity`='1',
    `price`='55',
    `subtotal`='55',
WHERE
    id=2
```

Comment: i want to add another row that will replace the id ='2'which values are 'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55' and put this in the id='3' so this means it will affect a row

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. You can INSERT a new row, which should give you an ID of 3; you can UPDATE the existing row, which would put the new data in the existing row. You can't replace a row with a primary, auto-indenting key and get a new key - all you can do is add a new row and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting, do not insert the primary key field:

```
INSERT INTO `f4`.`tbl_te` (
`name` , `quantity` , `price` ,`subtotal` )
VALUES ( 'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55' )
```

After inserting you can use the LastInsertID function too see what ID the database has assigned to your insert.

Comment: i want to add another row that will replace the id ='2'which values are 'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55' and put this in the id='3' so this means it will affect a row

Answer (score 0):

For inserting a row into a table that has a auto-increment field, you'll need to pass a `NULL` in place of the auto-increment field like

```
 INSERT INTO `f4`.`tbl_te` (
`id` ,
`name` ,
`quantity` ,
`price` ,
`subtotal`
)
VALUES (
NULL, 'Mushroom Omelet', '1', '55', '55'
)
```

and this will insert the row with the auto-incremented number.

If you want to update a existing row, use the usual update query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE f.tbl_te
SET 
 name = 'Mushroom Omlet',
 quantity = '1',
 price = '55',
 subtotal = '55'
WHERE
    id = 2;
```

Update the same record, if you want to replace that ID. You can't have multiples, so if it exists, update it. Although, that's not necessary, if you really want to change what id 2 is, this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you want to do, if you want to `INSERT` a new record to a table with autoincrement, you do not include that field:

```
 INSERT INTO `f4`.`tbl_te` 
 (
    `name` ,
    `quantity` ,
    `price` ,
    `subtotal`
)
VALUES 
(
    'Mushroom Omelet', 
    '1', 
    '55', 
    '55'
)
```

But if you want to `UPDATE` the values for that `id` then you use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `f4`.`tbl_te` 
    SET `name`  = 'Mushroom Omelet',
    `quantity` = '1',
    `price` = '55',
    `subtotal`= '55'
WHERE `id` = 2
```